# Border of asp:panel

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, border

What I make wrong in this snippet of code?? I would like to have border around two divs, but I see line (rectangle with no content). Have you any idea? This code is inside my WebControl.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pan" runat="server" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="1px" >
    <div style="width:18%; float:left;">
        <asp:Image id="img" runat="server" AlternateText="X" ImageUrl=""/>
    </div>

    <div style="width:78%; float:left;">
        <b><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button id="btnSet" runat="server" Text="Ustaw>"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label id="lblYouHaveCreditText" runat="server" Text="Masz kredytu na usługę"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did you try BackColor="Transparent" for asp:Panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<panel style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 500px; height:500px;" 
    id="pan" runat="server">

</div>
```

Heres' the jsFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/C5jqS/

When you're done, lose the inline CSS ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer - problem was you needed to specify a width and height.

Answer (score 0):

To get border for the panel, do the following :

- drag and drop panel on asp webform
- go to properties in grouping text and type the group name
- in border style select your choice.

[image: Screenshot]